# How to implement Modular Exponentiation Code

Tags: python, algorithm

Please I was learning from the book *Introduction to algorithm (Chapter 31 page 957)* and came across this pseudocode. This pseudocode is how we can implement the modular-exponentiation. The pseudocode is as follows

```
MODULAR-EXPONENTIATION(a,b,n)

1 c = 0

2 d = 1

3 let <b_k,b_(k-i),....b_0> be the binary representation of b

4 for i = k downto 0

5     c = 2c 

6     d = (d.d) mod n

7     if b_i == 1

8        c = c + 1

9        d = (d.a) mod n

10 return d
```

Then I tried to implement it in python

```
def modExpn(a,b,n):
    c = 0
    d = 1
    binary_of_b = f'{b:b}'
    len_of_b = len(binary_of_b)
    for i in range(len_of_b,0,-1):
        val = i - 1
        c = 2 * c
        d = (d * d) %  n
        if binary_of_b[val] == '1':
            c = c + 1
            d = (d * a) % n
    return d
```

But when I tried running the function (modExpn) with a = 7,b=560 and n = 561 the output I had was 415 but the right answer is 1. Please where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).  My mistake, nothing to see here

Comment: @HemersonTacon Please I tried several times and I am getting 415

Comment: Are you sure this is an accurate representation of the algorithm? The `c` variable doesn't seem to serve a purpose - it looks as if it should equal `b` in the end but it is never actually used for anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up while translating these parts from the pseudocode into actual code:

```
3 let <b_k,b_(k-i),....b_0> be the binary representation of b

4 for i = k **downto** 0
```

These instructions say that you should iterate from the left-most digit (b_k) of the binary representation to the right-most (b_0) since you need to go from `k` down to `0`.
When you transform, for instance, `8` to binary you get `"1000"`, and in Python the index of the left-most digit will be `0` and not `len("1000") - 1` as you are doing.
In other words, if you just do:

```
for bin_digit in binary_of_b:
```

and later:

```
if bin_digit == '1':
```

your code is going to work.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you __learned__ something here ;)

Comment: Yes I did. I really appreciate. But then I realized that when we take line 7 to 9 off, it still works. Please why then did they add line 7 and 9 ?

Comment: Are you sure it works for __all__ cases?

Comment: I can see it does not work for a =8 , b =50 and n =10. But please why so ?

Comment: Well, this is more a question of how the modular exponentiation works and not the code itself. Maybe it's best suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/ or another forum.